# Traversing an Unknown Level of Users for an Organizational Chart

Tags: php, algorithm, traversal

I'm working on an organizational chart in PHP, and the data is retrieved from a database.

An example of the organizational chart looks like the following, but it has an unknown number of levels:

Me

1. Brandon
2. David

   a. Amanda

   b. Michelle

   c. Michael
3. Robert

   a. Kristen

   - Charles
   - Ashley

Traversal-type algorithms has often been my weakness, and I need your help. I have experimented with many variations of a "traverse" function that would call itself, but I just haven't yet arrived at the proper solution.

The temporary solution I have right now is only three levels deep, and you can see why it's not realistic.

```
foreach($user->getChildren() as $child) {
    echo $child->name;

    foreach($child->getChildren() as $ch) {
        echo $ch->name;

        foreach($ch->getChildren() as $c) {
            echo $c->name;
            // ... more foreach statements
        }
    }
}
```

`$user` is of `class User`, and 
`$user->getChildren()` contains an array of User objects that have `$user` as their parent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your traverse function could look something like:

```
function traverse($users)
{
    if(empty($users)) return;

    foreach($users as $user)
    {
        echo $user->name;
        traverse($user->getChildren());
    }
}
```

So you have the stop condition which can be `if(empty($users)) return;` or `if(count($users) == 0) return;`, you get the idea, and the `foreach` loop on each level, which prints the name of the user, and calls the function again for the user's children.

You would call it as `traverse([$user]);` where `$user` is the user you want to start from.